# where is the typescript project item template file

Tags: typescript

i would like to programmatically add a typescript file to my project using VS automation through a t4 template. however i can't seem to find the typescript project item template file on my machine. does anyone know where it is installed? i am talking about the typescript file that one selects when using the "add new item" dialog of VS. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit Default TypeScript Template / Scaffolding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685674/edit-default-typescript-template-scaffolding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\enn4wcm5.z2b\IT\CSharp\1033\f.zip`

The `enn4wcm5.z2b` part will be different for every installation. I don't know how that's dealt with (or whether you have to) in t4.

Comment: (Hopefully this is obvious from the `CSharp` in there, but this will almost certainly change in some future version of TypeScript)